# How can I turn off automatic attribute quoting in Emmet-Vim?

Tags: vim, emmet

By default, when I expand an html tag with an attribute, the attribute's value gets surrounded by quotes.

e.g. `Route[component={Main}]` `->` `<Route component="{Main}"></Route>`

Whereas, when I'm using React, I want to have to specify when I want the expanded version to have quotes. In the example case I gave, I'd like this behavior:

`Route[component={Main}]` `->` `<Route component={Main}></Route>`

Is that possible with [Emmet-Vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Documentation:

`|g:user_emmet_settings| may be used to change attribute quote character`

So just set it to nothing (in vimrc):

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
  \    'html' : {
  \        'quote_char': ""
  \    }
  \}
```

for more info see section ***3.4. Quote character*** of [Emmet-vim Documentation](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/blob/52f3af7ca8bc6a9988fcd80c7189591330fbcadd/doc/emmet.txt#L830-L856).

**P.S.** If you are using *jsx* just replace that `'html'` by `'jsx'`

Comment: That solves the use case I mentioned, but I causes a lot more harm than good unfortunately. For example, I'd lose class quoting: `Story.short` -> `<Story class=short>`

Comment: Of course there is no need to any special setting to work with `jsx` files. just now test both `Route[component={Main}]` and `Story.short` in a `jsx` file and both correctly expanded to `<Route component={Main}></Route>` and `<Story className="short"></Story>` respectively, with the first one without qoutes and second one with qoutes in place.

Comment: Interesting! All of my React files are .js files... I wonder if there's a way to get the same behavior is `js` files.

Comment: Add to your *.vimrc*: `let g:user_emmet_settings = {'javascript': {'extends': 'jsx'}}`

Comment: I tried adding that like to my `.vimrc` and I still have the same behavior as before. `jsx` files actually behave the same way for me. Is it possible that `emmet` learned the behavior you wanted?

Comment: Strange! Because by now i have already got desired behaviour in both `javascript` and `jsx` file types. what is the output of `:echo &ft` when you are in a `.js` file?

Comment: When I run `:echo &ft` in a `.js` file right now I see `javascript.jsx`

Comment: So add to your *.vimrc*: `let g:user_emmet_settings = {'javascript.jsx': {'extends': 'jsx'}}` and everything should be ok. It seems you use *vim-jsx* plugin and it sets the filetype of javascript files to `javascript.jsx`.

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for the help!